# Electron cannot print multiple PDF files, error 3221225477

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, electron

I'm having some trouble with multiple PDF printing on Electron.

This is what happens in my JS: a function triggered by a click on a button hides the content that the user sees when the application starts and shows some other content, then this content is printed to a specific location. Once this is done, my js hides the current content and shows some other content, then calls the function that saves the pdf again and saves that pdf to another location.

The first file is saved and everything goes smooth but when i call again the function that prints the pdf then it throws an error at me, an error that is not even captured by the callback functions... (see images)

I've tried to switch the two PDFs creation and it's always the first that works, doesn't matter which content is displayed.
I've tried using both Async and Sync function to write the pdf file (fs.writeFile and fs.writeFileSync)
I've console.logged one by one all the data that i pass to the functions and they are all correct.

Here you can see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgYBx.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7GGV.jpg

ERROR i get in the console:

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 3221225477 npm ERR! (MY
>   PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0 start: `electron .` npm ERR! Exit status
>   3221225477 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0
>   start script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There
>   is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-09-28T13_37_12_330Z-debug.log

THIS IS THE DEBUG.LOG:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~prestart: (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\(MY PROJECT NAME)\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.4.11-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jre-11.0.4.11-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\liux_\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\MY_NAME\AppData\Local\atom\bin
9 verbose lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\(MY PROJECT NAME)
10 silly lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron .' ]
11 silly lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\(MY PROJECT NAME)
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the (MY PROJECT NAME)@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

Comment: I found out that using a sleep function to delay the execution of the next printing function solves the problem. However this is not normal, every function i used is SYNC and should not execute anything else until its finish... can someone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Electron would crash with status code `3221225477`.

**Problem**

The problem is that [`win.webContents.printToPDF()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprinttopdfoptions) is called too fast. It seemed that you need to wait a few milliseconds before you can call the function again.

**Solution**

Make sure to wait some time before starting the next print job. Put a statement like this behind your print statement to wait some time before starting the next print job:

```js
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
```

This code will wait for 100 milliseconds before continuing.